# Magento PHP Version Check correct?

Tags: php, magento2, ini

I'm installing Magento 2.1.7 on a Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS server.

Magento "Readiness Check" tells me:

> "Your PHP version is correct (7.0.20-2~ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)."

However, if I connect via SSH to the server and execute "php -i", the server tells me:

> "phpinfo() PHP Version = > 7.1.6-1~ubuntu16.04.1"

What is correct?

I am asking because Magento "Readiness Check" also tells me that the following PHP extentions are missing:

```
PHP Extension curl.
PHP Extension dom.
PHP Extension mcrypt.
PHP Extension simplexml. 
PHP Extension curl.
PHP Extension dom.
PHP Extension mcrypt.
PHP Extension simplexml. 
PHP Extension zip.
PHP Extension xmlwriter.
PHP Extension gd.
```

I have removed the leading semikolon to enable the extentions in both PHP

> version files [7.0]: /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini, [7.1]:
>   /etc/php/7.1/apache2/php.ini

```
extention=php_intl.dll
```

changed to

```
extention=php_intl.dll
```

Magento "Readiness Check" still tells me that the aforementioned extentions are missing. What needs to be done?

Comment: try to restart the apache2/nginx server and look again. Though it seems that you have 2 php installed, one for CLI and one in your magento.

Comment: I already restarted apache, but it still doesn't work even though I edited the configuration files of both php versions.

Comment: try to see what other php.ini you have on the server `find / -iname php.ini` and also be careful of what other .ini are extra loaded usually they are shwon in `php -i` (but this will not show you right if you have the wrong php version for your CLI), the same is with `php -m`, only that this shows you the installed modules.

Comment: Going by the package names, you have installed both PHP 7.0 and PHP 7.1 from the unofficial ondrej PPA. Is there a particular reason you're not using the official build of PHP 7.0?

Comment: @Phylogenesis How do the package names differ from the original ones? I deinstalled ondrejs pph by executing sudo ppa-purge ppa:ondrej/ppa. Now my php version is 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1.

Comment: @Jens I noted the `deb.sury.org` trailer on the PHP 7.0 version identifier and also the fact that there is no PHP 7.1 package in the official 16.04 repository. As per [this page](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/php7.0), 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 is the correct build that is supplied in the xenial-updates repository.

Comment: Now for the actual issue, Ubuntu does not configure PHP modules in the `php.ini` file. Typically, the configuration file is stored in `/etc/php/modules-available` and a soft link is created in the `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d` directory. Often this means that you can just `apt-get install` the appropriate php module if you know its package name (such as `php7.0-curl` or `php7.0-mcrypt`).

Comment: Note also that the line you uncommented in `php.ini` is under a section labelled `Windows Extensions`. The filename ends in `.dll` rather than `.so` as would be typical on a Linux system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by folling the hints of @Phylogenesis.

First I deinstalled the ondrej PHP version. After that only two php extentions were missing, which I could add by simply installing them via apt-get.

Comment: Glad to hear I helped.

Answer (score -2):

Magento 2 currently not support php versions great that php 7.0.x. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Comment: the version of the apache is 7.0.20

Comment: Yes, I also read that. But the Magento Readyness Check says: "Your PHP version is correct (7.0.20-2~ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)."